# Create a color box filling the entire right column of the first page of a two column article

Tags: tcolorbox

I am writing a two column paper and I am trying to have a contents table and and some text below it inside a tcolorbox in the right side of my first page. In the left side the documents text should start and continue normally towards the second page after the left column is filled.

I am trying to do this by having a floating tcolorbox in the right column of the first page. it works well, however I want it to fill the entire right side, but when I make the box a bit bigger than a certain "threshold" it goes to the next page. I also tried to pass the "height fill" parameter to the colorbox, but it also made it go to the second page.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin = 1in, left = 1.5cm, right = 1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}


\title{Some title for the document}
\author{author one, author two, and author three}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \lipsum[1-3]

    \begin{tcolorbox}[float,floatplacement=!t,height=0.751\textheight] %this is the largest I can make it, with "height fill" I does not work either
        %       \setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}
        %   \fbox{\colorbox{boxcolor!40}{
        %   \begin{minipage}[l]{0.94\linewidth}
        \small
        \tableofcontents
        \vspace{6pt}
        \rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}\vspace{8pt}
        \footnotesize
        \lipsum[3]
        %   \end{minipage}
        %}}
    \end{tcolorbox}

\lipsum[4]

\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\subsection{Subsection 3}
\lipsum[2]
\section{Section 2}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\subsection{Subsection 3}
\section{Section 3}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\subsection{Subsection 3}
\section{Section 4}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\subsection{Subsection 3}
\section{Section 5}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just a guess. The `float` option conflicts with `height fill` when you want to place it on the first page because part of `\textheight` is used with `\maketitle`.

Comment: You could try using TiKz to make the tcolorbox `overlay` and adjusting the first page `right margin` to be really big. But that would also break the text flow to the next page.
Just to note that I tried `\RLmulticolcolumns` and does break the flow of the next page inserting a `columnbreak` .